# relative path problem with Firefox

Tags: xslt

I have a question: relative path problem with Firefox..

I've the folder Order with the order.xml

an other folder is Source with code.xsl

In order.xml I've the string:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../Source/deliveryNote.xsl"?>
```

With IE all right but, Firefox not ok!

Thanks!

Gb

Comment: What?!?

Can you be more clear?

Comment: And tell us the structure of your folders.. 
Are they siblings or what..

Comment: fwiw, I have two complete online ordering systems using XML/XSLT/XPath with no path issues in Firefox or any browser.

Comment: I fire testers, who reports bugs in this way...

Answer (score 4):

There was a security adjustment in Firefox 3.

1. Go to **about:config**
2. Set **security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy** to **false**.

See John Resig's post on [Tightened Local File Security](http://ejohn.org/blog/tightened-local-file-security/).

Comment: But this assumes that documents are from local file system, so you should start your answer with *"If your documents are form local file system..."*

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, if you've got `code.xsl`, why are you referencing `deliveryNote.xsl`?

Relative paths for stylesheets seems to work fine in Firefox for me, so we're going to need some information, like what "not ok!" means, and what your folder structure actually looks like.